# C#: How to get typed variable from value in Object variable and type in Type variable?

Tags: c#

1. I have a value in a variable of type `Object`.
2. I have its type in a variable of type `Type`.
3. Type can be only among standard system types (Int32, Int64, etc..)

Q. I want to get bytes array representing this value. I'm trying to use `BitConverter.GetBytes` for that, but it requires a typed variable. Is there a way to get typed variable dynamically having a value and type in separate variables?

Thank you.

Comment: If you know the type, can't you cast? But generally speaking, this smells. You sure there isn't an easier way (polymorphism or generics perhaps)?

Comment: Yeah I agree, it smells like trying to get around the fact that C# is strongly typed.  Why do you think that you need to do what you have described?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to send some data to equipment, which understandably needs to be in byte array.
I want it to be open enough so that I could specify in one part of code number of values and their types, and it would form properly formatted byte arrays from that.
What I don't want to do foe each type is:
    `if (typeVar == typeof(int))  byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)valueVar);`
Or is it the only way to go?

    if (type)

Comment: @user817746: are you sending this via a stream or is it some custom interface that needs a byte array?

Comment: It's a udp packet, that I need to pre-format using the parameter data in it.

Comment: Nothing that a switch statement couldn't handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to `switch` on each type and call the appropriate method, which is the fastest way, you could use reflection, albeit a bit slower:

```
byte[] GetBytes(object obj)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    return (byte[])typeof(BitConverter)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Single(m => m.Name == "GetBytes" && m.GetParameters().Single().ParameterType == type)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { obj });
}
```

Calling `GetBytes((short)12345)` produces `new byte[] { 0x39 ,0x30 }`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public byte[] GetAnyBytes(dynamic myVariable) {
     return BitConverter.GetBytes(myVariable)
}
```

`dynamic` is essentially "I don't know what type this could be, check it at run time". Obviously, this is slower than using real types, but it is more flexible. Also, requires C# 4.0.

Comment: This is a great solution, if you're using .NET 4.0. And it's probably even faster than reflection since the DLR performs call site caching.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it. Unfortunately the project is not in C#4.0 at the moment (hope it will change soon), but I have access to C#4.0, and tested the reflection and the `dynamic` keyword approach. And can confirm `dynamic` word approach is 4 times faster!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this to get a byte array.

```
public static byte[] Object2ByteArray(object o)
{
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf = 
            new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(ms, o);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Although based on your description you may have made some poor implementation choices elsewhere.

found [here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/701574-object-memory-stream).

Comment: Should wrap that `MemoryStream` in a `using`-block.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Doesn't really matter for a `MemoryStream` which just has an internal array of bytes right?

Comment: This will produce vastly different results compared to `BitConverter`, and will most likely not be readable by the equipment he's sending that data to.

Comment: I will check this out. As long as it is byte array and it's bigendian it should do.

Comment: @Magnus: I agree, but given the contract it's worth future proofing the code block.

Comment: yes, this returned array of 35 bytes. What I'm really looking for is for `ushort` (say with value 12345 in it) to return a 2 byte array with bytes {0x39 ,0x30}.

Answer (score 0):

I'm concerned that you're trying to interact with another device using a binary format. Assuming the receiver of your data is not .NET, binary representations of data types varies from one device to another. I think you're better off representing this information in text, and using a parser to interpret the text.

Comment: unfortunately I don't define the format, it's a 3rd party equipment with proprietary format that I have to comply with. That's why I'm forming byte array, because it's easy to juggle. thanks for your interest!

Comment: What's the format? What's the architecture for integer? Is it big-endian or little-endian?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MemoryMappedFile`

```
private byte[] GetBytes<T>(T obj) where T : struct
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    using(var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("test", size))
    using(var acc = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
    {
        acc.Write(0, ref obj);
        var arr = new byte[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            arr[i] = acc.ReadByte(i);
        return arr;
    }
}
```